# Residue of the function: $\sin(\frac{1}{z^2+1})$ at $z = i$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Residue of $$\sin(\frac{1}{z^2+1})$$
at $z = i$.
I've tried to find its Laurent series, but it's seemed too complicated, so i don't know what to do..

Comment: Maple does not compute it.  So it must be tricky.  ($z=i$ is an essential singularity.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sin(1/(z^2+1)) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!\; (z^2+1)^{2k+1}}$$

Now taking $z = w + i$,
$$ \eqalign{\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^{2k+1}} &= \frac{1}{w^{2k+1} (w+2i)^{2k+1}}\cr
&= \frac{1}{(2iw)^{2k+1}}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j (2k+1)(2k+2)\ldots (2k+j)}{j!}\left(\frac{w}{2i}\right)^j }$$
so the residue of $1/(z^2+1)^{2k+1}$ at $z=i$, coming from the $j=2k$ term, is
$$ \frac{- 2 i}{(2k)!\; 4^{2k+1}} \prod_{j=1}^{2k} (2k+j) = \frac{-i (4k)!}{(2k)!^2\; 2^{4k+1}}$$
Thus the residue of $\sin(1/(z^2+1))$ at $z=i$ is
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{-i (-1)^k (4k)!}{(2k+1)!(2k)!^2 2^{4k+1}} $$
which according to Maple is
$$ -\frac{{i}}{2} \left(\cos \! \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) J_{0}\! \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sin \! \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) J_{1}\! \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$
where $J_0$ and $J_1$ are Bessel functions.

Comment: Oh, it really helps me, thank you!!